# Bash Trying to write name of converted file to text

Tags: bash, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have this script with which I convert my files to 16 bit. I would like to know which files have been converted so I try to write them to a list. However, the created file remains empty even when files have been converted. What is wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash
files=()
find . -name "*.wav" -o -name "*.WAV"|while read i; do
  if [ "$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=sample_fmt -of csv=p=0 "$i")" != "s16" ] || [ "$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=sample_rate -of csv=p=0 "$i")" != "44100" ]
    then
      ffmpeg -y -i "$i" -c:a pcm_s16le -ar 44100 "${i%.*}_16.wav";
      files+=("$i");
  fi
done

printf "%s\n" "${files[*]}" > converted_files.txt;
```

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Comment: Just printf or `echo "$i"` within the loop, and collect your desired data from stdout.